# Emotional TTS with Amazon Polly's SSML tags

Tags: amazon-polly

Polly allows the use of SSML tags which is great, but I cannot seem to find a tag that would add some kinds emotion. Let's refer to this as Emotional TTS. For instance, the following snippet:

```
<speak> Hi! My name is Joshua. </speak>

<speak> Hoi! Mijn naam is Lotte. <break time="3s" /> Ik lees elke tekst voor die je hier invoert. </speak>
```

Is it possible to do Emotional TTS with Polly; e.g. "aaaws" and "aaahs" with Polly? I guess if it were, it would have to be via SSML. Right? How would I modify the above to facilitate such a thing?

Comment: There is no such thing in Amazon Polly's SSML: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/supported-ssml.html

Comment: Thank you. I have seen that list. I wonder if you would know how to achieve emotional tts some other way? Perhaps by combining some existing tags; e.g. emphasis + Breathing + Changing the pitch etc... This would probably be a matter of taste if the outcome is desirable, but would you know of a TTS system to help me create such an output?

Comment: Just play sound

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Alexa, depending on language, you might be able to achieve some of this with speechcons:

```
<speak>
    Not quite "aah", but almost:
    <say-as interpret-as="interjection">argh</say-as>.
</speak>
```

See the supported list of speechcons and more details on:
https://developer.amazon.com/en-GB/docs/alexa/custom-skills/speechcon-reference-interjections-english-us.html

Unfortunately, Amazon Polly does not support interjections as of August 2021. You can try it interactively [in the browser](https://eu-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com/polly/home/SynthesizeSpeech?region=eu-west-1#) with the code above, which gives me:

```
The input you provided isn't valid. Check the input, and then try again.
```

Comment: Is there anything like this but for intonation? Like rising or falling intonation? If I have a question "are you calling about 1,2,3,or4?" rising intonation will give me a Yes/No question, but falling intonation will give me a multiple choice question. There doesn't seem to be an interpret-as question tag. But is there anything like this that could help me?

Comment: @alpablo20 have you tried "are you calling about 1, 2, 3, or 4?" vs "are you calling about 1, 2, 3, or 4?^" I think the latter, with "?^", should have rising intonation.

Comment: @TomaszNoinski I am very interested in rising intonation and tried `?^` with no results. Could you confirm?

Comment: @miguelmorin I'm not sure why it might not be working... I just confirmed in the test page of the AWS console (I used the default Joanna voice) and it worked for me.

Comment: @TomaszNoinski It works for Joanna as a Standard TTS voice, but not as a neural voice. Can you check if you used a neural voice?